# How to disable the onclick event once it happens?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, onclick

I had a image which calls `add_cart()` JavaScript function when `onclick()`

```
<img src="images/add.png" onclick="add_cart()">
```

I want the user to click the image only one time. When the user clicks it first time, `add_cart` function should be called. If he clicks second time no event should happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are dealing this on jquery side,you can use jquery `one` method

```
$(".myDiv").one("click", function(){  
    alert("this will happen only once");  
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 20):

```
<img src="images/add.png" onclick="add_cart(); this.onclick=null;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
<img src="images/add.png" onclick="this.onclick = function(){};add_cart();">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('myImageId').onclick = handleImageClick;
}

var handleImageClick = function(e) {
    var target;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;

    if(target) {
        target.onclick = function(){}

        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```