# Make onclick only occur once

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a text field with a default value. Onclick it's supposed to clear, but only clear once.
This is the code I'm using, but it completely overides everything. How should it be to make it so it clicks once but then after that it won't clear?

```
<div class="field clearfix wl_text_area">
              <textarea id="element_4_comment" name="element_4_comment" cols="45" rows="10" class="validate[optional] wl_text_area" onclick="(this).value='' this.onclick=null;">Enter additional information here.</textarea>
            </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438557/how-to-disable-the-onclick-event-once-it-happens Hope this helps.

Comment: `onclick="this.value=''; this.onclick=null;` - you forgot the `;`

Comment: you are missing semi colon!

Comment: gahh, thank you all. I can't believe I missed that. I didn't know if that was proper syntax to just put JS in a text area. Thanks again.

Comment: JS's compiler does strange things when semicolons are missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon:

```
<div class="field clearfix wl_text_area">
  <textarea id="element_4_comment" name="element_4_comment" cols="45" rows="10" class="validate[optional] wl_text_area" onclick="(this).value=''; this.onclick=null;">Enter additional information here.</textarea>
</div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b8JuD/

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery click binding method with one method.

$('#selectors').one('click',function(){

// do whatever you want on click

})