# How to register click event to element when it holds input+label?

Tags: javascript

Consider following markup:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox" />
  <label for="Checkbox">Click</label>
</div>
```

How do you assign a click handler to the `div` container that only executes once?

Comment: Where's the JavaScript that you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438557/how-to-disable-the-onclick-event-once-it-happens

Comment: You unbind it once clicked. Show how you bind it.

Comment: Do you want to click once on the checkbox or on the div?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to remove the listener in event handler. Something like that:

```
var div = document.getElementById('Checkbox').parent;

var clickHandler = function(event) {
  div.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  /* Do your stuff here */
}

div.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery there's documentation for this specifically. https://api.jquery.com/click/

Just give the div an id then add the click function in your javascript.

```
<div id="target">
  <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox" />
  <label for="Checkbox">Click</label>
</div>

$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Comment: The question isn't tagged with jQuery.